# how to automatically upload screenshots to Azure blob when pressing "print screen"using Azure blobs and Windows XP

Tags: ftp, windows-xp, azure-blob-storage

I would like to locate an existing software or simple  set up that works on XP (I'm beginning HTML, CSS and a bit of Jquery) so I can do the following:

a)"Shift + Prt Sc" lets me select a rectangle with the mouse, and deposits the image in my Azure Blob Storage container. This can be changed to another Azure container when needed.

I would like to have this image automatically upload onto the Internet and place a URL link in my clipboard. I want it to be automatic. As soon as foo.png appears in my Azure blob, the copy to clip board needs to execute.

DropBox does the screenshots and url copy but it goes to their blob while I need it to go to mine. With Jing I'm able to take screenshots and have the url copied to my clipboard however i only got it to work to my hosted website's image folder as Azure Websites has an FTP link but Azure Storage Blob do not show such an FTP link.

b) the same as above but instead of getting to selecting a rectangle with my mouse, I want the entire screen real estate to be taken as the image and automatically upload onto the Internet and place a URL link in my clipboard when I press "Prt Sc"

How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks, Lukkha i use Cerebrata and Cloudberry to upload to Blob but that does not automate the process to get my screenshot with url in clipboard. Maarten's write-up is from 2010 - things change on a regular basis in Azure, maybe there's new features. Hoping someone may know how to do exactly what I need reliably without having to bend the system too much.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nothing that will do exactly what you want. Options below:

1. You could use Cerebrata's free [Azure Explorer tool](http://www.cerebrata.com/download/azure-explorer) to upload images and get a url, but I am not sure if it will work on XP.
2. Follow this blog post by Maarten Balliauw on [Using FTP to access Windows Azure Blob Storage](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/03/15/Using-FTP-to-access-Windows-Azure-Blob-Storage.aspx) and use it in combination with what you have already done.